# Summing adjacent digits

Tags: bash, shell

I'm receiving input in the below format (emitting each bit in a bitfield as the individual digit that bit represents). I want to add those digits, to get the overall value for each field as a separate digit, as below. What is the best way to do it?

```
421 401 401
421 401 401
421 401 401
421 401 001
```

Output should be:

```
755
755
755
751
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Since the first value will *only ever* be 4 or 0, the second will *only ever* be 2 or 0, and the last will *only ever* be 1 or 0, this doesn't even need to be implemented as a summing operation as such; it could just as easily just be implemented by ORing together the values associated with the non-zero bits (and not even the specific values in the input, but the value calculated via `1<<position`, with the right-hand being position==0). Asking the question in a way that leaves out details about your context and input thus restrains the set of answers that can be given.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking how to sum adjacent digits in a text file, try

```
awk '{
    # Loop over tokens on each line
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        # Is this token all numbers?
        if ($i !~ /[^0-9]/) {
            # Yes: Loop over numbers and sum them
            sum = 0
            for (j=1; j<=length($i); ++j)
                sum += substr($i, j, 1)
            # Finally replace the value with the sum
            $i = sum
        }
    }
# Print every input line after possible substitutions
}1'  filename.txt
```

Sample output:

```
7 5 5
7 5 5
7 5 5
7 5 1
```

The shell can read lines from a file and perform arithmetic on integers, but it's really not a good fit for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's just loops. This doesn't confirm your input format, though you could.

```
while read -a bits                  # real the lines from your example
do for cnhk in "${bits[@]}"         # walk through each group
   do  declare -i i=-1 tot=0        # initialize working vals
       while (( ++i<${#chnk} ))     # walk through the digits
       do (( tot += ${chnk:$i:1} )) # total them
       done
       printf "$tot";               # print each digit
   done
   printf "\n"                      # newline after each set
done < datafile
```

If I understand what you're doing, you could as easily use symbolics, though your apparent expectations would make them all flat assignments and you lose most of the benefits...

```
declare -A prm=( [0]='' [1]=x [2]=w [4]=r )
declare -a ugo=( u g o )
while read -a bits
do sym=''
   for chnk in 0 1 2
   do  sym="$sym,${ugo[$chnk]}="
       for p in 4 2 1
       do case "${bits[$chnk]}" in
          *$p*) sym="$sym${prm[$p]}" ;;
          esac
       done
       sym=${sym#,}
   done
   printf "%s\n" $sym
done  < datafile
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
u=rwx,g=rx,o=x
```

Comment: `set` being a builtin, it's maybe not a great variable name. At least messes up the syntax highlighting a bit.

Comment: Truth. Meant to change that, will do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
$ cat adj_digits.txt
421 401 401
421 401 401
421 401 401
421 401 001

$ perl -pe ' s/(\S)/$1+/g; s/(\S+)/eval("$1 0")/ge;s/ //g ' adj_digits.txt
755
755
755
751
```

If you want to split and use @F, then

```
$ perl -lane ' for(@F) { $sum=0; $sum+=$_ for split(""); printf("%s",$sum); } print "" ' adj_digits.txt
755
755
755
751
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="[ \n]" '{       
    n=split($0,a,"")       # separate chars into a array
    for(i in a)            # each array element
        if(a[i])           # if >0
            a[0]+=2^(n-i)  # power and sum to a[0]
    printf "%s%s",a[0],RT  # output with stored separator
}' file
```

Output:

```
7 5 5
7 5 5
7 5 5
7 5 1
```